# Burn hex with optiLoader

Tags: arduino-ide, atmega328, bootloader, avr

Can [optiLoader](https://github.com/WestfW/OptiLoader) be used to burn custom hex?

For example, there's hex representation stored in optiLoader.ino in `image_328`, if that value is replaced with content of my pre-compiled hex, should that work right out of the box or some additional tweaking is needed?

**EDIT**

Discussion about the same topic on [arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=535153.0) as well.

Comment: ISP is for writing hex. bootloader or program or booth together. why do you want to use optiload? AVRISP sketch in IDE examples does it too.

Comment: The reason why I want to use it is because I want to try it without IDE, basically without computer. So I just want to write firmware on new blank IC by pressing a button from my proto board. 
AVRISP in should work as well, but I feel like I will have to change much more code in order to make it to work without IDE, because it's using Serial to get data and pass it to target IC, right? ...and if optiLoader works as I thought above, then I can just simply replace HEX content with my.

Comment: ISP is not Serial. ISP uses SPI connection

Comment: It does but only to talk with target IC, but communication between programmer IC and IDE is done via serial.

Comment: @Juraj BTW I was referring to these methods `getch` and `avrisp` in that ArduinoISP sketch.

Comment: ok, I understand, you want to have the hex as part of the flashing sketch. but hex is more then twice larger then the binary representation of the program. you would be limited to a small program with hex. or you want to use SD card to store the hex?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, for now I would like to stick with small program with HEX. Later I want to move to SD card to store hex.

Comment: sure is, it is possible. the esp8266 AVRISP library does it with SPI connected AVR. the HEX is first received over WiFi there. try it with optiload. btw, WestfW is active on arduino.cc forum

Comment: Thanks @Juraj I will take a look at this one as well.

Comment: What do you **really** want to do? Burn a bootloader, or burn some useful code that does something? (A bootloader is just for uploading code)

Comment: *hex is more then twice larger then the binary representation of the program* - So? The .hex file stores each byte as readable hex, so the byte 0xAB is stored as "AB". However it only takes up one byte in the program memory.

Comment: Also see [parse intel hex into SPI commands for arduino ICSP AVR](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50352/parse-intel-hex-into-spi-commands-for-arduino-icsp-avr/50353#50353)

Comment: @NickGammon this looks amazing! So, basically in order to achieve what I mentioned above, in your sketch I would just need to replace this part `ifstream sdin (fName);` in `readHexFile` method, to read from `hard-codded` value, instead of using SD card as data source. Ofc, to remove the part related to display, sd card, etc. but this is how you are reading content of that HEX file, line by line?

Comment: @NickGammon, what was wrong on my statement about the size? the 'more' was for line endings

Comment: @Juraj - I didn't see why "you would be limited to a small program with hex". The hex digits in the .hex file are just an intermediate way of representing the same data. There is no limitation in size because you are reading from the .hex file.

Comment: @NickGammon, it was about in-memory hex. like the in-memory  bootloader hex in OptiLoader, Chris has it strong in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work provided that your desired target image is stored in the same form, with correct metadata, and that **it is small enough to fit in the programmer device**.

The storage format of the payload-to-program could be made more optimal by a factor of almost two; however, for the original purpose of injecting compact Arduino-style bootloaders that is scarcely needed, and would have made preparing payloads more complicated.